# How to open a CSHTML file as HTML file in Google Chrome?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to view a Razor file in Google Chrome. It's possible if you change de extension file ".CSHTML" to ".HTML". So,  any idea how can i adopt a better solution?

Comment: Do you mean locally i.e. default editor or do you want to serve them?

Comment: Locally. Just dragging and dropping the .CSHTML in Google Chrome. My workmate works with Sublime Text editor and he needs to visualize the file in browser.

Answer (score 0):

in your Global.asax file. From there go inside of or create the Application_AcquireRequestState function as so:

void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

Inside the above function check to see if the path matches your .cshtml file. If so, do Server.Transfer to a regular aspx page.

Comment: Thanks! But i need a solution outside of Visual Studio or running the application. My workmate uses Sublime Text editor and he needs to visualize the file in browser.

Comment: well, that's easy, you can just right click open with chrome, then it will do it, if not ,change the extension to be html, should do it though!

Comment: I guess your mate is a php developer, I was using sublime for php, it's quite handy.

Comment: @user3334708 If thats all he wanted he could just drag and drop. I think he wants the html actually rendered.... just like when he renames it to an *.html.

Comment: well, to render the cshtml file, you need razor engine, there is no way to render it fully without razor engine, in other words, you can not view the final html code without razor engine

Comment: another way will be, you run the application, view the final html page, copy the html source code to your work mates, he can save it as html page file

Comment: exactly @rism!  i can open just drag and drop the file, but after that i renamed the file to ".HTML".I would't want to do this before.

Comment: @user3334708 in this moment we are working in this way. I'm trying  to "bridge the gap" between a front-ender and  a back-end develloper like me. Today we work with two different repos.

Comment: well, I got an idea, if you are working with asp mvc, you can render your view to string, then post the string back to the browser, you work mate just need a js to append it to a html body element